# Is there a way to call an item in a list each time using a for loop?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, list-comprehension

I am wanting to print out a sentence getting each item in a list to generate a new sentence.  I would also like to be able to do this when using list comprehension if possible.

I tried looking through all of my resources with no luck.

```
>>>squared = [17, 100, 25]
>>>my_iterator = iter(squared)

>>>for multiplied in iter(squared):
...    x = next(my_iterator) ** 2
...    print("The square of {0} in list 'squared' is {}".format(???, x)
```

What should I put for ??? (in print line above).  I am trying to say:
"The square of 17 in list 'squared' is 298"
"The square of 100 in list 'squared' is 10000
etc...
Is it possible to do the same thing with list comprehension?

```
>>>new_squared = [i **2 for i in squared]
print(???)
```

I have tried putting .format(my_iterator, x) but the only thing that pops out is the memory allocation or something... and .format(next(my_iterator), x) doesn't work.

Comment: Put `multiplied` in place of `???`.

Comment: wow... it was that easy... Well thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're asking. Are you just looking for this?

```
squared = [17, 100, 25]

for x in squared:
    print("The square of {} in list 'squared' is {}".format(x, x ** 2))
```

Output:

```
The square of 17 in list 'squared' is 289
The square of 100 in list 'squared' is 10000
The square of 25 in list 'squared' is 625
```

Comment: Yes.  Thank you.